# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I Upgrade my android studio to 3.0.0 and face this type of issue in my existing project , Anyone have sol ?

Error:

> Execution failed for task
>   :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: LICENSE

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'}

Comment: Add this in question section.

Comment: `packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya its not workin ;(